# Online Form with Conditional JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, conditional-statements

On this form, I need to have a condition on the first 2 buttons clicked.

If button 1 and button 2, then show the `div` id.

I did have some `switch` statements on a separate script, but it conflicted with the JavaScript for the next/prev buttons, as they are set to hide/show as well.

I do have CSS that hides all `class` "tab".

Any ideas?

Can I add to the current JavaScript that I have now?

```
<form id="auto_form" novalidate action="action.php"  method="post">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./three.css">
 <h4> Auto Insurance Quote </h4> <br>
 <div id= "year">
 <div class="tab">
 <input type= "button" id="2019" value="2019" name="showform" 
 onclick="findmodel(this.value)";</button>
 <input type= "button" id="2018" value="2018" name="showform" 
 onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
 <input type= "button" id="2017" value="2017" name="showform" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="2016" value="2016" name="showform" 
 onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
 </div>
  </div>


 <div id= "make">
 <div class="tab">
  <input type= "button" id="chevrolet" value="CHEVROLET" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value)";</button>
  <input type= "button" id="dodge" value="DODGE" name="showform" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="ford" value="FORD" name="showform" 
 onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="honda" value="HONDA" name="showform" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="hyundai" value="HYUNDAI" name="showform" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="kia" value="KIA" name="showform" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="nissan" value="NISSAN" name="showform" 
  onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
  <input type= "button" id="toyota" value="TOYOTA" name="showform" 
   onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
   </div>
   </div>


  <div id= "chevy_2018">

   <div class="tab">
     <input type= "button" id="bolt_ev" value="BOLT EV" name="showform" 
   onclick="findmodel(this.value)";</button>
    <input type= "button" id="showform" value="CAMARO" name="showform" 
   onclick="findmodel(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="CITY EXPRESS" name="showform" 
   onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="CRUZE" name="showform" 
  onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="EQUINOX" name="showform" 
  onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="EQUINOX LIMITED" 
  name="showform" onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="EXPRESS G2500" name="showform" 
   onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="EXPRESS G3500" name="showform" 
   onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
   <input type= "button" id="showform" value="IMPALA" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="showform" value="MALIBU" name="showform" 
   onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
    <input type= "button" id="showform" value="SILVERADO" name="showform" 
     onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="showform" value="SONIC" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
        <input type= "button" id="showform" value="SPARK" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
    <input type= "button" id="showform" value="SUBURAN" name="showform" 
   onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="showform" value="TAHOE" name="showform" 
     onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="showform" value="TRAVERSE" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="showform" value="TRAX" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
    <input type= "button" id="showform" value="VOLT" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="showform" value="OTHER" name="showform" 
     onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     </div>

    <div id= "gender">

    <div class="tab">
    <input type= "button" id="male" value="MALE" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="female" value="FEMALE" name="showform" 
    onclick="showhideForm(this.value);"</button>
        </div>

     <div id= "name">

        <div class="tab">
     First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
         Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
        </div>

     <div id= "dob">
      <div class="tab">
    <input type= "button" id="jan" value="JAN" name="showform" 
   onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
      <input type= "button" id="feb" value="FEB" name="showform" 
      onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
      <input type= "button" id="march" value="MARCH" name="showform" 
      onclick="next(this.value);"</button><br>
       <h6> Day You Were Born </h6> <br>
      <input type= "button" id="1" value="1" name="showform" 
    onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
      <input type= "button" id="2" value="2" name="showform" 
      onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="3" value="3" name="showform" 
     onclick="next(this.value);"</button><br>
    <h6> Year You Were Born </h6> <br>
    <input type= "button" id="2000" value="2000" name="showform" 
    onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
      <input type= "button" id="2001" value="2001" name="showform" 
      onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
     <input type= "button" id="2002" value="2002" name="showform" 
      onclick="next(this.value);"</button>
        </div>


     <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
       <button type="button" id="prevBtn" 
       onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" 
      onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        </div>

       <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
       <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
         <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
          <span class="step"></span>
         <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        </div>

        </form>


      <script>
      var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
      showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

        function showTab(n) {
     // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
          x[n].style.display = "block";
            // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
            if (n == 0) {
         document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
            } else {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
     }
         if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
     document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
     } else {
       document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
         fixStepIndicator(n)
          }

     function nextPrev(n) {
     // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
       // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
       if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
           currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form... :
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
           //...the form gets submitted:
          document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
           return false;
              }
          // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
          showTab(currentTab);
           }

            function validateForm() {
          // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
       x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
          y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
           // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
             if (y[i].value == "") {
              // add an "invalid" class to the field:
              y[i].className += " invalid";
              // and set the current valid status to false:
               valid = false;
                }
           }
                 // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished 
         and valid:
          if (valid) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " 
         finish";
            }
          return valid; // return the valid status
             }

              function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
           var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
                 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
              x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                   }
              //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
           x[n].className += " active";
             }
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would have to store state of the button(s) that have been clicked in your onClick() function.

You might also have to extend functionality of your findmodel function to determine which button has been clicked.  Something like `findModel(this.value, this.id)` to track which button ids' have been clicked.  Once you've determined that two unique button ids have been clicked, show your div.

I don't see `findModal` code in the snippet you posted, but that should give you a good idea of how to approach the problem.

Good luck!